# 3D surface plot with complex z matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I have x, y, z as:

```
x = list(range(20, 100, 20))
y = list(range(100, 200, 20))
Z = function(x, y, a, b)
```

where a is a Dataframe with datetimeindex and single column, b is a boolean series, and function gives an array Z((len(x), len(y))), function is a nested loop with other functions used inside.
I wanted to plot a surface that shows how z change with x and y by:

```
X = list(range(20, 100, 20))
Y = list(range(100, 200, 20))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = function(x, y, a, b) 
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, inewidth=0, antialiased=False)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

However i got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/simulation.py", line 82, in <module>
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
  File "C:\Users\baili\PycharmProjects\import_yahoo_data\venv_1\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 1621, in plot_surface
    X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in broadcast_arrays
  File "C:\Users\baili\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 264, in broadcast_arrays
    shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
  File "C:\Users\baili\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 191, in _broadcast_shape
    b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I think it has something to do with the z function....but I am not sure exactly how.....
Thanks !

Comment: oh....yeah, sorry

Comment: Thanks! Could you also add the result of `print(X.shape)`, `print(Y.shape)`, `print(Z.shape)`?

Comment: only can print z.shape =(4, 5)

Comment: x and y are all list

Comment: x = [20, 40, 60, 80]

Comment: y = [100, 120, 140, 160, 180]

Comment: **x** (lowercase) and **X** (uppercase) in your code are two different variables (same applies to y/Y). `x` is a list, `X` is an array (the result of `np.meshgrid`).

Comment: that is my typo here, sorry, in my code they are all lower case.....I havent understood ..

Comment: shape of x =(5,4)....shape of y=(5,4)....shape of z=(4,5)......seems not quite right